# Angular cli npm start failed

Tags: command-line, angular, angular2-cli

I'm using angular-cli for my first angular 2 project, but it generates the error below when I use `npm start` command

```
Running without elevated rights. Running Ember CLI "as Administrator" increases performance significantly.
See ember-cli.com/user-guide/#windows for details.

Livereload failed on http://localhost:49156.  It is either in use or you do not have permission.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ng-app@0.0.0 start: `ng server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ng-app@0.0.0 start script 'ng server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ng-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ng server
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ng-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     ...\ng_app\npm-debug.log
```

I check all my prerequise for my machine because I have, node v5.5.0, typings 1.3.2, but it still generates the same error.

What I missed?

Thank you in advanced!

*Edited* :
I run the `npm start` command this morning, and it has the following error:

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink
```

Comment: I hope you are through with ng init command so all the node modules are installed, Can you add the info about task which gets executed when you run `npm start` and also what is the version of angular cli you have?

Comment: see at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1600

Comment: @MadhuRanjan: angular-cli: 0.1.0
node: 5.5.0
os: win32 x64

Comment: Run the `CMD` as `Admin` and try again.

Comment: @eg16, I still have the `Broccoli` error

Comment: Are you sure the port 49156 is available ? You can try to access URL http://localhost:49156 to check.

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux, it returns `{"tinylr":"Welcome","version":"0.2.1"}`.
And according @eg16, I run the command as Admin, and the port `4200` is available, but when I check into console of dev tool, it has `zone.js:323 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/system-config.js(…)` as error, so how can I solve this?

Comment: You have probably another process running. Try to close all the other ng serve and restart a new one.

Comment: Thank you guys, it works now! 
I restart my computer to make sure that all process stop.

Answer (score 1):

From the question answer, it was related to another process using the port 49156 which is required by Angular CLI for auto reloading. 
To be sure, there is nothing using the port you can request the URL http://localhost:49156/. If you do not find the process, a restart can solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: This 49156 port is not the serve port, i think, it is a test port

Comment: It is the port used to handle reloading of the page such that when you modify a file, the cli build and once ready it triggers the reload of the browser using this port.